# SharePoint via web services: how to add attachments?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

Adding a list item via the SharePoint web service model, any idea how to add an attachment to the list item?

Comment: Thanks for adding these questions and answers into the system. Could you please tag your questions with `sharepoint`? The web services apply to both WSS 3.0 and SharePoint 2007. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing Alex, retagged this one, will tag em correctly in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wsLists.AddAttachment(this.ListName, listItemID, safeFileName(attachment.Name), File.ReadAllBytes(attachment.FullName));
```

safeFileName function =

```
 private string safeFileName(string filename)
        {
            filename = filename.Replace(@"\", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"/", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@":", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"*", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"?", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"""", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"<", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@">", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"|", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"#", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"{", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"}", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"%", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"~", "");
            filename = filename.Replace(@"&", "");
            return filename; 
        }
```

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thanks for the safe filename function. I have to implement this very thing next week.